# Get file descriptor of stdout c

Tags: c, shell

stdin, stdout, stderr file descriptors are 0, 1 and 2 by default. However after I open a file by `fd = open(foo, 0)`, I find `fd` now is 1. 1 is used for the new file descriptor. What is stdout file descriptor now? Or it is closed and I need to reopen it? If yes, how? Is there a way to keep 0, 1, 2 file descriptors and use from 3?

```
/* readslow from the book with my "improve": the unix programming environment */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define SIZE 512
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char buf[SIZE];
    int n, fd;
    int t = 10;

    if ((argc > 1) && (fd = open(argv[1], 0) == -1)) {error("can't open %s", argv[1]);}
    fprintf(stderr, "%d", fd);

    for (;;) {
        while ((n = read(fd, buf, sizeof buf)) > 0)
           write(1, buf, n);
        sleep(t);
    }
}
```

`fprintf(stderr, "%d", fd)` will give me 1.

Comment: Please show your code that produces that result. That is, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @kaylum I update my question with my code.

Comment: It is all my fault. I miss the ")" in `if ((argc > 1) && (fd = open(argv[1], 0) == -1))`. It is really hard to find this error. Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code contains the fragment:

```
if (argc > 1 && (fd = open(argv[1], 0) == -1))
```

The result in `fd` is as if you'd written the comparison inside parentheses:

```
if (argc > 1 && (fd = (open(argv[1], 0) == -1)))
```

So the result assigned to `fd` is correctly `1` because the value returned by `open()` is indeed `-1`.  You should have parentheses around the assignment:

```
if (argc > 1 && (fd = open(argv[1], 0)) == -1)
```

Comment: yeah, I realize it now. I don't mean to do this. Stupid as it is. It happens to me sometime

Comment: Most of us have made that sort of mistake at some time.  It does demonstrate the importance of showing the code.  With the code, the explanation is easy.  Without the code, we can only hypothesize — and what is hypothesized isn't necessarily relevant once the code is shown.

Answer (score 5):

[*There was no code in the Question when this Answer was composed. I had accepted the OP's claim that the file descriptor returned by `open` was `1`, which turns out to be untrue due to a misplaced paren.*]

> *I find `fd` now is 1. 1 is used for the new file descriptor.*

The only way that would happen is if you closed fd 1.

> *What is stdout file descriptor now?*

`fileno(stdout)` will give you the `fd` associated with the handle.

> *Is there a way to keep 0, 1, 2 file descriptors and use from 3?*

If you don't close fd 0, 1 and 2, they won't be reused. `open` uses the lowest-numbered unused file descriptor.

If you wish to disconnect fd 0, 1 or 2, don't close them. That causes all sorts of problems. Re-open them to `/dev/null` instead.

> *Or it is closed and I need to reopen it? If yes, how?*

You can use `dup2` to make an fd an alias of another one.

Comment: This answer is correct. In fact, I find I miss a ")"  in my code which result in this chaos. Your answer make me more clear of file descriptor. Thanks

Comment: This answer was reasonable when posted — but then the code was added to the question, and this becomes mostly tangential.  As far as it goes it is accurate, but the code has a major precedence flaw unrelated to closing file descriptor 1 or using `dup2()`.